# is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: batch-file, command

I want to run a batch file but I have a problem. The content of test.bat is :

```
echo on
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%i in ('ping -n 1 proxy ^| find /I /N "Pinging"') do set USED_PROXY_SERVER=%%i
@echo Your are using the following Proxy=%USED_PROXY_SERVER%
```

It told me

```
'ping -n 1 proxy ^| find /I /N "Pinging"' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

The ping and find command can be used in command line.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

works perfectly on my machine - so, your environment must be screwed up.

try

`set path=%path%;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32`

before you run your batch file

Or, to be sure that the windows commands are being run

`set path=c:\windows;c:\windows\system32;%path%`

Comment: Then what you entered (posted) and what you ran are not the same, or you are not running your command through the 'usual' command processor/shell.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason :**

the System variables : ComSpec has been modified.